# serversocket to bluetooth serversocket

Tags: android, c++, node.js, sockets, bluetooth

For the past couple of days, I have been working on establishing a client-server socket over Bluetooth with an android server and a windows PC socket so I can send information over from the computer that can be used on an app for Oculus Gear VR (app would be on the android). I am having a big issue with the Bluetooth server socket on the android side. It doesn't help that my experience with android studio is encompassed within like 4 days. I figured out how to create a regular server socket on an android app that waits for a connection from the client
`public class MyServer {
    BluetoothDevice device;
    Thread  m_objThread;

```
ServerSocket m_server;
String m_strMessage;
DataDisplay m_dataDisplay;
Object m_connected;
public MyServer()
{

}
public void setEventListener(DataDisplay dataDisplay)
{
    m_dataDisplay = dataDisplay;
}
public void startListening()
{

    m_objThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                m_server = new ServerSocket(2001);
                Socket connectedSocket = m_server.accept();
                Message clientmessage = Message.obtain();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connectedSocket.getInputStream());
                String strMessage = (String) ois.readObject();
                clientmessage.obj = strMessage;
                mHandler.sendMessage(clientmessage);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connectedSocket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject("Hi..");
                ois.close();
                oos.close();
                m_server.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Message msg3 = Message.obtain();
                msg3.obj = e.getMessage();
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg3);
            }

        }
    });
    m_objThread.start();
}
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message status)
    {
        m_dataDisplay.Display(status.obj.toString());
    }
};
```

`
But I am not completely sure how to change this to a Bluetooth server socket in order to create a Bluetooth socket. Any help is appreciated, I am relatively new to coding and have only used c++ on visual studio so I am having a lot of trouble with android studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create one thread for accepting a connection and another- for sending and receiving the data. When device is connected, you stop 'connect thread' and start 'transfer' thread. There is a gread example from google- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat